# How to append char data to a std::vector without causing a copy

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector, unsigned-char

I have a vector of chars which contains some data elements.

```
std::vector<unsigned char> data_1;
```

I have an unsigned char * which is pointing another set of data elements.

```
unsigned char * data_2;
```

**Question:**
Is there a way I can merge `data_2` into `data_1` which is a vector without causing a copy of the data elements at all?

I read about move semantics being referred in [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10488348/add-to-vector-without-copying-struct-data) but I am a bit unsure if it is possible in this situation I have here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way I can merge data_2 into data_1 which is a vector without causing a copy of the data elements at all?

No. All ways of inserting elements into a vector require copying (or moving) each element at least once.

> I read about move semantics being referred in this discussion but I am a bit unsure if it is possible in this situation I have here.

Moving a char is same as copying a char. The distinction is only relevant to class types with a non-trivial move constructor or move assignment operator.

> It wouldn't be possible even if data_2 was a `std::vector<unsigned char>`?

*Appending* without copying (or moving) would not be possible even then.

Sidenote 1: You can *replace* the entire content of one vector with content of another vector without copying (or moving) any elements by using move assignment operator of the vector.

Sidenote 2: You *can* merge two instances of node based containers such as `std::list`s, `std::set`s, `std::map`s and their unordered counterparts without copying (nor moving) any of the elements.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't do that.

- Vector data is stored contiguously, so unless your buffers were already back-to-back somehow (which they're not), at least one of them needs to be moved (read: copied)
- Vectors can't take ownership of existing memory (your `unsigned char* data_2`)
- Vectors can't own two blocks of memory simultaneously (a hypothetical `std::vector<unsigned char> data_2`)

You can, however, at the point of use, make it so that *it doesn't matter* by [having a single iterator type "jump" from the first buffer to the second, transparently](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/105230/2503).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. It wouldn't be possible even if `data_2` was a `std::vector<unsigned char>`? I know its still not possible but wish to confirm once.

Comment: @AdeleGoldberg: No (though at least then the second bullet point would not be [directly] applicable)

Answer (score 1):

No. `vector`s are stored contiguously; while you could avoid reallocation of `data_1` by `reserve`ing enough space for the complete size of the concatenated data before populating `data_1`, you can't avoid the actual copy of the bytes; the data must be moved to a position contiguous with the existing data in `data_1`, and a `vector` cannot avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. But then you'd have to have custom allocator for the vector.

By default, `vector` uses [`std::allocator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator), and you may use [`vector::get_allocator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/get_allocator) to get the allocator object. You may try using `allocator::construct` method do to some manipulation (I didn't dig deeper on that).

When you instantiate a `vector` you can pass a custom-allocator to the vector, which would help to use already allocated memory (*placement new*), or any other memory allocation function. [This article](https://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/stl/article.php/c4079/Allocators-STL.htm) may help.

However, I don't think such an effort is really fruitful.

Comment: Is it possible to write an allocator that provides access to _two_ independent blocks of memory as if they were one?